# What is the best recommended AuthN and AuthZ flow for Server to Server integration?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

There are N number of products (MS) exposed their api to the outer world through the API gateway. We federated the API gateway with IDP and following OAUTH2.0 flow but what should be the best Authentication process for server to server integration of API where we don't need to explicitly redirect the user to browser to enter credentials.

Answer (score 2):

The [client credentials flow](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-client-credentials-flow/) is what you're after. It's an OAuth flow designed for service to service communication. The client presents its credentials to the Authorization Server (IDP), e.g. a secret or a certificate in an mTLS scenario, and gets back an access token that identifies just the client (not any user). The flow does not need a browser and is a simple HTTP request-response.

Comment: This secret is generated after authentication of the client right ? i.e. we need to have a authentication server to validate the credentials and generate secret which will be validated by IDP ?

Comment: You register the client at the Authorization Server (which sometimes can be the IDP). Usually, it's done manually. You obtain a client ID and a client secret. These are then added to the client's configuration. Then, the client can call the authorization server to obtain access tokens. If these are JWTs, then anyone can validate those tokens. Otherwise, they are validated by the Authorization Server (the same server which issued the tokens).